# NSEntityDescription still exist in memory?

Tags: ios, core-data

Now I have a Core Data entity "AAA", and I use a method to fetch its result:

```
- (AAA *)result{
    NSEntityDescription *Entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AAA" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:aaaEntity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchRequestResult = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    AAA *aaa = fetchRequestResult.lastObject;
    return aaa;
}
```

Then I use Xcode Instruments to check the memory status, it shows:

```
VM:Core Data Object IDs 4.02MB(Live Bytes)
```

Is the entity still live in the memory?

Comment: Is the Core Data Object IDs will always exist in the memory until I stop running my App.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would start to say that you should not be worried about memory when you deal with Core Data. Under the hood the framework manages stuff for you. When you retrieve an object, Core Data populate a cache where data are stored in. In this way, further fetches will not hit the disk but the cache only.

Anyway, you could rely on two different APIs to control memory footprint. The first one is `[context reset]`. This will clear the entire object graph (that belongs to a specific context) as if you had just created it.

The second one is `[context refreshObject:yourManagedObject mergeChanges:NO]`. It allows releasing an object, or turning it into a fault.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Steve.DC.Tang Sorry. I don't understand what you're asking. Could you explain better?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ~ BTW, We can use NSFetchResultController to fetch result from a entity ,but it seems more suitable for UITableView.Except the NSFetchResultController,does the pattern above(like my method) is the only way to fetch the result from a entity?

Comment: To fetch results, you use a `NSFetchRequest`. But you can return different result types as described in documentation. See `resultType` https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSManagedObjectResultType

Comment: "you should not be worried about memory when you deal with Core Data" - no, it depends what you're doing with core data. Sometime you might need to think about this.

Comment: "further fetches will not hit the disk but the cache only" - this is too vague. Further fetches of what exact nature? Further fetches of only that exact entity can hit the row cache only, sure. But surely the fetch request shown will still check the persistent store to see if any new instances of that entity type exist.